# Adwhril with Millinial media,ZestAdz and InMobi is giving errors

Tags: android, adwhirl

I tried to implement Adwhril and added Millenial Media,ZestAdz and InMobi network to it.I have also setup up house ads for back up.

Now the problem is that when Adwhril tries to show ads from InMobi than a big blank black screen appears and application hangs and nothing happens after that.Everything is stuck.It is not even throwing any warnings or errors.

Only ads that gets displayed is my HouseAd(Custom Ad).None of the others ads are showing up besides HouseAd :(

When it tries to show ads from Millenial Ads than i get the following errors:

```
09-06 21:37:04.227: D/AdWhirl SDK(281): Valid adapter, calling handle()
09-06 21:37:04.234: W/AdWhirl SDK(281): Caught an exception in adapter:
09-06 21:37:04.234: W/AdWhirl SDK(281): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.millennialmedia.android.MMAdView.<init>
09-06 21:37:04.234: W/AdWhirl SDK(281):     at com.adwhirl.adapters.MillennialAdapter.handle(MillennialAdapter.java:77)
09-06 21:37:04.234: W/AdWhirl SDK(281):     at com.adwhirl.adapters.AdWhirlAdapter.handle(AdWhirlAdapter.java:168)
09-06 21:37:04.234: W/AdWhirl SDK(281):     at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout.handleAd(AdWhirlLayout.java:231)
09-06 21:37:04.234: W/AdWhirl SDK(281):     at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout.access$300(AdWhirlLayout.java:53)
09-06 21:37:04.234: W/AdWhirl SDK(281):     at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout$HandleAdRunnable.run(AdWhirlLayout.java:399)
09-06 21:37:04.234: W/AdWhirl SDK(281):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-06 21:37:04.234: W/AdWhirl SDK(281):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-06 21:37:04.234: W/AdWhirl SDK(281):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-06 21:37:04.234: W/AdWhirl SDK(281):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-06 21:37:04.234: W/AdWhirl SDK(281):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-06 21:37:04.234: W/AdWhirl SDK(281):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-06 21:37:04.234: W/AdWhirl SDK(281):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-06 21:37:04.234: W/AdWhirl SDK(281):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-06 21:37:04.234: W/AdWhirl SDK(281):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-06 21:37:04.234: D/AdWhirl SDK(281): Showing ad:
09-06 21:37:04.234: D/AdWhirl SDK(281):     nid: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
09-06 21:37:04.234: D/AdWhirl SDK(281):     name: custom
09-06 21:37:04.234: D/AdWhirl SDK(281):     type: 9
09-06 21:37:04.234: D/AdWhirl SDK(281):     key: __CUSTOM__
09-06 21:37:04.234: D/AdWhirl SDK(281):     key2: 
09-06 21:37:04.234: D/AdWhirl SDK(281): Generic adapter will get destroyed
```

When it tries to display ZestAdz than i get following messages

```
09-06 22:02:44.063: D/AdWhirl SDK(328): Showing ad:
09-06 22:02:44.063: D/AdWhirl SDK(328):     nid: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
09-06 22:02:44.063: D/AdWhirl SDK(328):     name: zestadz
09-06 22:02:44.063: D/AdWhirl SDK(328):     type: 20
09-06 22:02:44.063: D/AdWhirl SDK(328):     key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
09-06 22:02:44.063: D/AdWhirl SDK(328):     key2: 
09-06 22:02:44.063: W/AdWhirl SDK(328): Unsupported ration type: 20
09-06 22:02:44.122: D/dalvikvm(328): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2068 objects / 351008 bytes in 53ms
09-06 22:02:44.132: W/AdWhirl SDK(328): Caught an exception in adapter:
09-06 22:02:44.132: W/AdWhirl SDK(328): java.lang.Exception: Invalid adapter
09-06 22:02:44.132: W/AdWhirl SDK(328):     at com.adwhirl.adapters.AdWhirlAdapter.handle(AdWhirlAdapter.java:170)
09-06 22:02:44.132: W/AdWhirl SDK(328):     at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout.handleAd(AdWhirlLayout.java:231)
09-06 22:02:44.132: W/AdWhirl SDK(328):     at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout.access$300(AdWhirlLayout.java:53)
09-06 22:02:44.132: W/AdWhirl SDK(328):     at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout$HandleAdRunnable.run(AdWhirlLayout.java:399)
09-06 22:02:44.132: W/AdWhirl SDK(328):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-06 22:02:44.132: W/AdWhirl SDK(328):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-06 22:02:44.132: W/AdWhirl SDK(328):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-06 22:02:44.132: W/AdWhirl SDK(328):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-06 22:02:44.132: W/AdWhirl SDK(328):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-06 22:02:44.132: W/AdWhirl SDK(328):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-06 22:02:44.132: W/AdWhirl SDK(328):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-06 22:02:44.132: W/AdWhirl SDK(328):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-06 22:02:44.132: W/AdWhirl SDK(328):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone please point it out what is that im doing wrong and guide me on how can i solve this problem?

Thank You!!

Comment: You have too much ads & did not add `com.millennialmedia.android` properly to your project

Comment: @zapl tank for the response.i get the same error even if i turn off 2 out of those 3 ad networks.Also i have add millennialmedia SDK in project build path and in the libs folder.I have no clue what else am i suppose to do.I did exactly what was suggested in AdWhril docs.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have included the latest version of the adapters and sdks.
Also check that you have added the network id of the networks you are integrating with in the adwhirl site.

Here is the sample code to use the same.
In xml file add

```
<com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout
    android:id="@+id/adwhirl_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Code changes:

```
AdWhirlLayout adWhirlLayout2 = new AdWhirlLayout(this,"46a9e26bb1f5499ab7b00c9807ae034b");
adWhirlLayout2.setAdWhirlInterface(this);
adWhirlLayout2.setMaxWidth(width);
adWhirlLayout2.setMaxHeight(height);
AdWhirlManager.setConfigExpireTimeout(1000 * 60 * 5);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adWhirlLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
adWhirlLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
layout.addView(adWhirlLayout2, adWhirlLayoutParams);
```

Dont forget the permissions.

Please post your code.It will be easier to debug.
In case of any queries please reach helpdesk@inmobi.com